# RxJs - How to manually push data from observable that lives in parent

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable that lives in the parent which is polling via timer.  The observable is passed to the child where a lot of info is displayed and has a bunch of actions.  After successful action I need to call API again from the parent and continue polling.  How can I do this?  This is what I have so far:

**Stackblitz to easier demonstrate**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-api-call-wrnybf

**app.component.html**

```
Total Count: <span *ngIf="users$ | async as users">{{users.length}}</span>

<hello [users]="users$"></hello>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  users$: Observable<User[]>;

  getList() {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users$ = timer(1, 10000).pipe(
       switchMap(() =>
      this.getList().pipe(
        tap(x => console.log(`${x.length} results retrieved`))
      ),
      shareReplay(1)
    ));
  }
```

**hello.component.html**

```
<h3 (click)="manualRetrieval()">Click to Force Reload</h3>

<div *ngIf="users | async as userList">
    <div *ngFor="let user of userList">
      {{ user.title }}
      </div>
</div>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
  @Input() users: User[];

  manualRetrieval() {
    console.log('this should manually update the results (getList call from parent) after a successful different API call in this component');
  }
```

Comment: Your code is self contradictory. `@Input() users: User[];` is correct because your pass it an array via the `async` pipe in the parent component. This makes `*ngIf="users | async as users"` invalid in `hello.component.html`

Comment: I've updated it to `*ngIf="users | async as userList`

Comment: Yep - you can see in the console it calls every 10 seconds for demo purposes.  What I would like is to manually make an API call.  The polling in real is actually every 120 seconds.  On success of an API call in the child component - I would like to manually update `getList` since I don't want user to wait at most 120 seconds for updated data.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood because I was distracted by the weird use of `async` in `hello.component` because the property is an array. I see what you are trying to do now however.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

#### hello.component.ts

```js
@Output() retrieve = new EventEmitter();

manualRetrieval() {
  console.log('this should manually update the results after a successful different API call');
  this.retrieve.emit();
}
```

#### app.component.html

```html
<hello 
  [users]="users$"
  (retrieve)="retrieveManually.next()"
></hello>
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
retrieveManually = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.users$ = merge(timer(1, 10000), this.retrieveManually).pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
    this.getList().pipe(
      tap(x => console.log(`${x.length} results retrieved after 10 secs`))
    )
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-api-from-parent?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html).

Comment: Elegantly done: +1. PS. I hate that `shareReplay` is named `shareReplay`.